# Communicating with website on apache tomcat from website on IIS

Tags: asp.net, web, tomcat, iis

Problem:
We have a website written in ASP.NET hosted on an IIS server.
We want to start developing a new website using Java, Springboot, and AngularJS and want to deploy on a web server on the same machine (most probable apache tomcat).

For certain DOM elements on the ASP.NET website, after clicking on them I should be routed to the appropriate web page on the new website hosted on the tomcat.

How can we achieve this communication between these two websites?

Answer (score 0):

If your DOM element is a link (the HTML anchor tag) you can just put the new website page's link as the href property and will just work. You can pass parameters in the query string.

If you are trying to submit a form on the ASP.net page to an end point on Tomcat, then use the Tomcat endpoint as the action property of form. Here you have an option of choosing GET/POST as the method.

If you are tyring to do Ajax requests from the ASP.net page to a Tomcat endpoint, you will get into a CORS issue. There are plenty of articles/tutorials on how to add a CORS header on Tomcat-SpringBoot that will help you out.